# how to extract column names based on a condition?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Consider this simple example

```
mytest <- data_frame(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                     x = c(NA,NA,NA,5,6,7),
                     other_var = c(NA, NA, NA, 1,2,3),
                     y = c(3,5,6,NA,NA,NA),
                     another_var = c(1,2,3, NA,NA,NA),
                     label_x = c('hello','hello','hello','world','world','world'),
                     label_y =c('bada','bada','bada','boom','boom','boom'),
                     label_other_var = c('ak','ak','ak','run','run','run'),
                     label_another_var = c('noo','noo','noo','bie','bie','bie'))

# A tibble: 6 x 9
  group     x other_var     y another_var label_x label_y label_other_var label_another_var
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>           <chr>            
1 a        NA        NA     3           1 hello   bada    ak              noo              
2 a        NA        NA     5           2 hello   bada    ak              noo              
3 a        NA        NA     6           3 hello   bada    ak              noo              
4 b         5         1    NA          NA world   boom    run             bie              
5 b         6         2    NA          NA world   boom    run             bie              
6 b         7         3    NA          NA world   boom    run             bie
```

Here, I need to `nest()` this dataframe by `group`, and be able to extract the column names of the variables (in each nested dataframe) that are not NAs. The trick is that the *actual name of the variable* is shown in the `label_` column

For instance, this is the output desired:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  group var  
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     bada 
2 a     noo  
3 b     world
4 b     run
```

Indeed, take group `a`. There is only one non-missing variables are `y` and `another_var`. However, the name of `y` is `bada` (as shown in the `label_y` variable) and the name of `another_var` is `noo`. Same reasoning for `b`.

I dont know how to do that with a `map` call after running

```
mytest %>% group_by(group) %>% nest()

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  group data            
  <chr> <list>          
1 a     <tibble [3 x 8]>
2 b     <tibble [3 x 8]>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

EDIT: the original, smaller, tibble proposed was the following

```
 mytest <- data_frame(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
+                      x = c(NA,NA,NA,5,6,7),
+                      y = c(3,5,6,NA,NA,NA),
+                      label_x = c('hello','hello','hello','world','world','world'),
+                      label_y =c('bada','bada','bada','boom','boom','boom'))
```

Comment: can you also keep the original dataset and have this as update so that I don't have to change the original answer.  Will do an update on the answer

Comment: OK I can add the old one as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After group by `nest`ing, loop through the 'data' with `map`, `summarise` the the 'label' columns by extracting the `first` non-NA element, `gather` it to a single column while removing the `NA` (`na.rm = TRUE)`), `select` the 'var' column, and then do the `unnest` (after keeping only the columns of interest)

```
mytest %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest %>% 
  mutate(var = map(data, ~ 
                     .x %>%
                      summarise(label_x = label_x[!is.na(x)][1], 
                                label_y = label_y[!is.na(y)][1]) %>% 
                      gather(key, var, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
                      select(var))) %>%
  select(-data) %>% 
  unnest
# A tibble: 2 x 2#
#  group var 
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a     bada 
#2 b     world
```

#### Update

If there are more columns, create unique column names and then loop through the corresponding column names with `map2`

```
nm1 <- unique(sub("label_", "", setdiff(names(mytest), "group")))
nm2 <- paste0("label_", nm1)
mytest %>% 
   group_by(group) %>% 
   nest %>%
   mutate(var = map(data, ~ 
                    map2_chr(.x %>% 
                               select(nm1),
                             .x %>%
                              select(nm2), ~ 
                                .y[!is.na(.x)][1]) %>% 
                                   na.omit %>%
                                   tibble(var = .))) %>% 
    select(-data) %>%
    unnest
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  group var  
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a     bada 
#2 a     noo  
#3 b     world
#4 b     run
```

Comment: Hi akrun this is nice but I cant really generalize. That is, in my dataframe, there are many different variables (with different names). However, the `label` variables always have the form `label_X` where `X` is a given variable. I am thinking about using `summarize_if` here, but dont see a clear path... any ideas? thanks!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ  I was going to ask you about that.  If you have a corresponding `label` column with suffix part as the actual column name, then we can loop through the names of the columns to do it

Comment: yes, let me create a slightly bigger example so that the loop makes more sense. thanks again !

Comment: done! thanks again and yes, this is actually useful in real life :)

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ  Updated the post

Answer (score 1):

This will output the result you want:

```
mytest <- data_frame(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                     x = c(NA,NA,NA,5,6,7),
                     y = c(3,5,6,NA,NA,NA),
                     label_x = c('hello','hello','hello','world','world','world'),
                     label_y =c('bada','bada','bada','boom','boom','boom'))

extract_good_colnames <- function(df, subgroup){
  subset <- filter(df, group == subgroup)
  if(sum(is.na(subset$x)) > 0){
    colname = 'label_y'
  }else if(sum(is.na(subset$y)) > 0){
    colname = 'label_x'
  }
  return(tibble(group = subgroup, var = as.character(subset[1, colname])))
}

groups <- unique(mytest$group)
map_df(groups, function(x) extract_good_colnames(mytest, x))
```